# Unable to understand why the background color isn't filling the whole screen when I use TailwindCss and Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am using tailwindcss for styling my application, however when i try to set the background color it does not fill the whole space but leaves some part of the screen as white.

App.vue

```
<template>
  
 
  <div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col bg-cyan-500 ">
    <site-navigation></site-navigation>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SiteNavigation from './components/SiteNavigation.vue'
/*eslint-disable*/
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    SiteNavigation,
  }
}
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>

  <header>
    <nav>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </nav>
  </header>

</template>


<script></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn46r.png)

I tried reading the documentation and saw that viewport needs to be correct which indeed is in my index.html file.

Comment: You should inspect the DOM with your browser's dev tools to see what's really going on.  You should be able to figure out what element/component the empty space belongs to and/or what CSS is responsible.  One possible explanation is there's margin at the top of the page